# Area of a Cross Section GRASS GIS 7

Tags: grass-gis, area, profile

I have a task I would like to solve with GRASS GIS 7, if somehow possible. 
I want to create a cross section from a landslide - and would like to calculate the area of that cross section/profile. Any way to do this easily without using ArcGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question right, take a look at [r3.cross.rast](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r3.cross.rast.html) which creates cross section 2D raster map from 3D raster map based on 2D elevation map. From that 2D map you can generate the area report.

Comment: Markus, many thanks! 
Yes, I believe this function would enable me to do this. I have solved the issue for now with a spreatsheet that calculates the area from the cross section, but r3.cross.rast would be a better solution.

Best, 
Peter